# Switch between secure and non-secure DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryservices

I am struggling with the following, this is what I have now and it is working but.

```
 public PrincipalContext getPrincipalContext(bool secured)
 {
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
        secured ?  DomainName + ":636" : DomainName,
        Container,
        secured ? ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate : ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
        userName,
        password);
    return oPrincipalContext;
 }
```

want to do something like this

```
secured ?  PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            DomainName + ":636",
            Container,
            ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate 
            userName,
            password); 
        :
          PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            DomainName,
            Container,
            ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
    return oPrincipalContext;
```

I think this is possible but can not get it to compile. Can someone help me with the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this:

```
 PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = secured ? 
         new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            DomainName + ":636",
            Container,
            ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate 
            userName,
            password); 
        :
          new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            DomainName,
            Container,
            ContextOptions.SimpleBind );
```

or why don't you just use `if, else`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for